# VSTO C# in Powerpoint: WindowSelectionChange Event

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I am new to VSTO and C# and have a question regarding events.
I'm trying to fire an event when the user selects something within PowerPoint (e.g. a shape, slide, etc).

I found a working solution for VBA in the Office documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.windowselectionchange) and some more info for a Word selection handler [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954166/word-document-selectionchange-event-does-not-fire), however I'm clueless on how and where to add it in my **ThisAddIn.cs** context.

I'm currently working from a fresh C# PowerPoint VSTO Addin
[image: Blank C# PowerPoint VSTO Addin]

Any pointers into the right direction are highly welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-create-event-handlers-in-office-projects?view=vs-2022) and it works:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.WindowSelectionChange += Application_WindowSelectionChange;

}

private void Application_WindowSelectionChange(PowerPoint.Selection Sel)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}
```